# UNIX run program within another program

Tags: c, unix

I am trying to execute a program from within a C program (inside UNIX).

I have been given an executable ( the program requires a string input during execution and writes that input to another file called sample ) called exec and I want to execute it in program.c, but giving the string input through indirection.

For that I created a file as follows:

```
% vim input
```

I wrote the following inside the input file

```
content
```

Now in program.c,

```
#include<unistd.h>
int main()
{
      const char* command = "./exec < input";
      execvp(command, NULL);
      return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, the content is not entered into the sample file.

But when I run it without indirection, i.e.

```
const char* command = "./exec";
```

then it works, and input entered in saved in sample file.

Can someone please tell what am I doing wrong in the indirection syntax.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax you are using is supposed to be interpreted by a shell like bash, csh, ksh, etc.

The system call `execvp` only expects the path to the executable and a number of arguments, the shell is not invoked there.

To perform redirection in this manner, you'll have to use the `dup2(2)` system call before calling `execvp`:

```
int fd = open("input", O_RDONLY);
/* redirect standard input to the opened file */
dup2(fd, 0);
execvp("/path/to/exec", ...);
```

Of course, you'll need some additional error checking in a real-world program.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do redirection like that with `execvp`.  Use `system()` or start getting friendly with `dup()` and friends.  You might google 'implementing redirection'.. you'll likely turn up plenty of examples of how shells (for example) handle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [`exec(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) family of functions does not know anything about input redirection or parsing command lines: it tries to execute exactly the executable you give it.  It's trying to search for an executable file with the name `"./exec < input"`, which unsurprisingly does not exist.

One solution would be to use the [`system(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) function instead of `exec`.  `system` invokes the user's shell (such as `/bin/bash`), which is capable of parsing the command line and doing appropriate redirections.  But, `system()` is not as versatile as `exec`, so it may or may not be suitable for your needs.

The better solution is to do the input redirection yourself.  What you need to do us use [`open(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/open) to open the file and [`dup2(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dup2) to duplicate the file descriptor onto file descriptor 0 (standard input), and then `exec` the executable.